# recognize_google speech recognition broken pipe python

Tags: python, youtube, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I have an audio file (30 seconds) and want to convert it into text using google.

I am following this guide :

https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/#working-with-audio-files

my code is the following :

cut=sr.AudioFile("cutsound.wav")
with cut as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
r.recognize_google(audio)

Now i get this endless error message :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BrokenPipeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1317                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
-> 1318                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1319             except OSError as err: # timeout error

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1238         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1239         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1240 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1284             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1285         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1286 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1233             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1234         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1235 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1064                         + b'\r\n'
-> 1065                 self.send(chunk)
   1066 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in send(self, data)
    985         try:
--> 986             self.sock.sendall(data)
    987         except TypeError:

BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py in recognize_google(self, audio_data, key, language, show_all)
    839         try:
--> 840             response = urlopen(request, timeout=self.operation_timeout)
    841         except HTTPError as e:

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    222         opener = _opener
--> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    224 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    525 
--> 526         response = self._open(req, data)
    527 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _open(self, req, data)
    543         result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
--> 544                                   '_open', req)
    545         if result:

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 504             result = func(*args)
    505             if result is not None:

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in http_open(self, req)
   1345     def http_open(self, req):
-> 1346         return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
   1347 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1319             except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1320                 raise URLError(err)
   1321             r = h.getresponse()

URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 32] Broken pipe>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RequestError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-59c33ef07a2e> in <module>()
----> 1 r.recognize_google(audio)

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py in recognize_google(self, audio_data, key, language, show_all)
    842             raise RequestError("recognition request failed: {}".format(e.reason))
    843         except URLError as e:
--> 844             raise RequestError("recognition connection failed: {}".format(e.reason))
    845         response_text = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    846 

RequestError: recognition connection failed: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Answer (score 3):

The method described in your link uses hacks and not guaranteed to work reliably. Google blocks long files or excessive requests.

Google has an [official API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) which you can use to recognize long files, it is paid though:

Answer (score -1):

yeah hi! In my case, I just connected the internet and it worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).